# automatically scaling dashboards based on a resize event

Tags: reporting, iccube

The live dashboard demo for icCube shows dashboards that scale with the size of your browser window. At the moment, though, after you resize the window, you have to refesh your browser first to see the re-scaled dashboard.

Is it possible - and how - to scale automatically after you resize the window (so without pressing F5)?

Comment: the functionality can be seen in http://www.iccube.com/livedemo/

Comment: Not sure to understand the issue; the report is being resized once the browser window has been resized and you should not need to refresh the browser. Is this about an embedded report into your own application?

Comment: It is an embedded report, similar to the demo:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 5.1.1 it is now fixed and it works.
It took me a while to get it working, since I was referencing to a different version of jquery in the main page (jquery-1.11.2.min.js).

After I changed it to the jquery version in icCube (jquery-1.7.2.min.js) it worked.

I do not know why this is the case, but it is working and that is the main thing that counts.

Answer (score 0):

My javascript developer foung the following solution. It is not perfect, but it works:

- in the main dashboard that acts as a menu (using the embedded report widget), place an action/button with the event ic3-report-refresh in it
- make the button invisible with CSS
- place the following code in the javascript section for the main dashboard:

  ```
  function consumeEvent( context, event ) {   
  if (event.name == 'ic3-report-after-build') {     
        //resize window
        var delay = (function(){
            var timer = 0;
            return function(callback, ms){
              clearTimeout(timer);
              timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
            };
          })();


  $(window).resize(function () {
      delay(function(){
      $(".report-refresh-button").trigger("click");
  }, 500);
  });
  ```

  }
  }`

The effect is that when the main html page (in which the main dashboard is embedded) changes in size (i.e. iPad turns), a refresh is triggered which effectively triggers icCube to resize the page.

Comment: In case of embedded reports the refresh was not working (version 5.1), but now its fixed, you can check the livedemo.

Comment: Can you help me a little bit. I can not see it working in the live demo.

When I resize the window, the CSS applies mediascreen style, but icCube is not really responding as it still uses the same sizing and positioning of elements.